# How to save random flash player videos on disk?

Tags: flash, video-capture

Is there some utility to capture and save Flash player videos on disk? I'm talking about different random websites, not any particular site.

I've tried some Chrome extensions but most of them don't seem to work or only work in rare places or YouTube only.

Comment: You said you have tried some extensions in Chrome what about [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) that claims to work with many sites? It is for Firefox though

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sothink SWF Catcher](http://www.sothink.com/product/swfcatcher/). It does what you are looking for.

[image]